# UWP: Deployment error: Cannot register the xxxxx package because the extension is missing an EntryPoint or StartPage attribute. (0x80073cf6)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

I try to create an JS UWP App with a win32 fullTrustProcess AppService extension. I followed the example here: https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample but when I try to deploy to local machine (Windows 10 with anniversary update) then I get a deployment error:

```
DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. AppxManifest.xml(49,10): error 0x80080204: Cannot register the xxxxx package because the extension is missing an EntryPoint or StartPage attribute. (0x80073cf6)
Deployment of the application to the target device failed.
```

The extension part of the manifest:

```
<Extensions>
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService"> <!-- line 49 from error -->
        <uap:AppService Name="CommunicationService" />
    </uap:Extension>
    <desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="bin\mywin32.exe" />
</Extensions>
```

Comment: Seems like the fullTruseProcess extension has not supported for WINJS project, I will confirm this internally and come back soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work in WINJS UWP app, please follow these steps:

1. Add `EntryPoint` attribute for the fullTrustProcess extension:

`<desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="BackgroundProcess.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication" />`

2. Set `StartPage` attribute for appService extension:

`<uap:Extension Category="windows.appService" StartPage="index.html">
              <uap:AppService Name="CommunicationService" />
            </uap:Extension>`

3. Change the `TargetDeviceFamily` to `Desktop` and ensure `MinVersion` above 14257:

`<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14393.0" />`

Check my demo here: https://github.com/Myfreedom614/UWP-Samples/tree/master/AppServiceBridgeSample

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out soon.

Comment: Now the project deploy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Now how do I get the AppServiceConnection instance to call SendMessageAsync?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Unfortunately i couldn't get it solved using the solution proposed by Franklin Chen.

I fixed this problem by starting a new windows universal project and make sure i use only the very latest versions of the Windows universal templates (in my case a background task).
Right after creation, i deployed this to the Raspberry Pi. After this succesfull deploy, i copied the code from my old project to this new project and i arrived where i wanted to be.